# wordpress, a download manager for outside URLs

Tags: wordpress, media, download-manager, hosted

I'm working on a online file library for one of my clients.  It's a library for mostly PDFs and office documents.  Because they are a huge amount(almost 2gb in files), I'm hosting them on another site(divshare), so that the hosting account we have doesn't get blocked by the excess of files, and also because of excess traffic downloading can generate.

So, my question is if there is a good download manager(even with some search for download categories and so) that can handle instead of local uploaded files, URLs of files hosted somewhere else?

The advice about any plugin or the like is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to code such manager, right? Otherwise, your are on the wrong site...

I think you need to make a kind of file manager, except that instead of generating HTML pages to view the files and act on them, it exposes a Web API, returning XML or Json data, that a WordPress plugin can manage.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that coding it was the way to go, but had some kind of hope someone may know about some plugin or 'something' that 'maybe'(quite a longshot, right?) could do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

From Divshare:

> The DivShare Uploader Plugin for Wordpress replaces your regular
>   uploading frame with a DivShare upload form, allowing you to easily
>   upload and add files without ever leaving your "Write a Post" page.
>   It's a great way to speed up your blogging and take the load off your
>   servers when hosting big files and images.

It can be found here: http://www.divshare.com/integrate

Good Luck!

Marcelous

Comment: I was thinking about using the DivShare api for managing the digital library, but from the google group they recommended me to skip it and use the Kadoo service.  Is divshare going to be closed in order tu put more effort on Kadoo?